# Can automator run when Macbook lid is closed?

Tags: automator, automation

If i set an automator scrip to run each evening at 23:00 but my Macbook / Macbook Pro is closed (not off, but the lid has been closed) will / can the automator script still run ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the Automator workflow will not run when your MacBook's lid is closed.

This is because your Mac is asleep and not actively running user applications and processes. You can [prevent your Mac from sleeping when the lid is closed](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=stop+mac+sleeping+on+lid+close&t=osx). Be aware that this is not recommended by Apple.